# How Can I Bring In Changes To Git From TFS Since The Git Repository Was Created?

Tags: git, tfs

We have an application which used TFS for source control.
We switched to Git and brought the code over from TFS.
Some development then took place and new changes were checked into TFS.
There have been no changes made yet in Git.

How can I now update the Git source with the changes in TFS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: Redo the git migration? Reapply the changes to the existing git codebase?

Comment: When you say you used TFS for source code - do you mean TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) or just used TFS to host your Central Git Repo?

Comment: TFVC - I didn't use TFS to host Central Git Repo.

Comment: How did you do your migration? With 'git-tfs'? Or just copying the files?

Comment: I didn't do the migration. The coworker that did is no longer with the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you migrate from TFVC to GIT the best practice is to lock the TFVC repo and **NOT** keep working on him.

But if you didn't lock and some people did a check-in with new code to TFVC, you can use the tool [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) (I guess you used him for the migration) to pull the changes from TFVC to your new Git repo.

The command is: `git-tfs pull [options]`

The `pull` command fetches TFS changesets (like the `fetch` command) and merges (or rebase using `r` option) the current branch with the commits fetched (creation of a merge commit or rebase all the commits).

See more info and examples [here](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/pull.md).